# Multiplie simple Selects from array of tables in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, mariadb

I want to make a simple select from array of tables.

I am using DBeaver for work. I need to extract the most recent record using field which present in all tables.

I need to do it with MariaDb and Oracle databases.

The query I want to perform is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
ORDER BY message_dt DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

I want to retry this query for several tables (without executing it manually, placing table name in select query; cause is I want to automate the test check) and have an output either in single console text field, either in file. I need to save column names, though, so UNION maybe will not work.

I tried to do this in PL/SQL (extracting only the data, not column names), but it's not working for me:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE TBLS_ARR IS VARRAY(NUM_OF_TABLES) OF VARCHAR2(128);
  TBLS TBLS_ARR := TBLS_ARR('TABLENAME_1',...,'TABLENAME_N');
  type TOP_RECORD is VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. TBLS.COUNT LOOP
    SELECT *
    INTO TOP_RECORD
    FROM TBLS(i)
    order by message_dt desc limit 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOP_RECORD);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The error I get for mariadb is: You have an error in your SQL syntax.

The error I get for oracle is smth like: encountered wrong symbol.

Preferably, I want to have all results of queries stored in Excel file like:

```
FIRST_TABLE_COLUMN_NAMES[]
FIRST_TABLE_COLUMN_RECORD[]

SECOND_TABLE_COLUMN_NAMES[]
SECOND_TABLE_COLUMN_RECORD[]

...

Nth_TABLE_COLUMN_NAMES[]
Nth_TABLE_COLUMN_RECORD[]
```

Or in the comfortable table view.

Comment: You will not be able to code that runs on PL/SQL and on Mariadb as well.

Comment: Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` clause. From Oracle 12 you can use `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: Okay, so I should try PL/SQL on Oracle and some UNION query on mariadb.

Comment: When you declare a varray type, the max length must be a literal integer, it can't be a variable like you seem to want. But why do you need a varray in the first place? That should be a nested table (a collection where the order of memebers is not relevant).

Comment: You cannot do what you want, at least the way you are going about. An SQL statement cannot object names as variables thus `from tbls(i)` will not work, you need dynamic SQL. Your declaration for TOP_RECORD defines a `type`, not a variable

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I think I've found a workaround.
I am load tester and used JMeter to be able to make multiplie similiar requests.